# Install key search bin registry

Tags: c#

I have came up with a program that will find the install key of certain software, the issue is with Nero as it changes the key every time you reinstall the software.
example under Nero\Shared\NL11 you can find the install key under Serial11_1625650388 now the issue is after reinstalling the software the entry changes to lets say Serial11_162587194. How can I fine the relevant key after it changes or is there a way of finding the changed key by showing the keys entry which would be the install key, i.e. read the entry of the key if that makes sense. Here is the code I use to retrieve the key

RegistryKey registry = null;
switch (key)
{
// Open the CDKey subkey readonly.

```
        case Key.Snn18Win10:
            registry =
              Registry.LocalMachine.
                OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Nero\\Shared\\NL11",
                  false);

            if (registry != null)
                
                
            Snn18Win10 = ("Serial11_1625650388");
    
          
            else

                registry =
                          Registry.LocalMachine.
                            OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Nero\\Shared\\NL11",
                              false);
            if (registry != null)
                Snn18Win10 = ("Serial11_1625650388");

            break;
    }
    if (registry != null)
    {

        Snn18Win10 = registry.GetValue("Serial11_1625650388")
```

Comment: If the keys are changing on a regular basis, there's a *strong* reason to believe that this is deliberately done. Maybe, just maybe, they do not want other programs to mess about with their registry keys/values. Why should we enter this "war" on your side?

Comment: This maybe true but this is just a install key recovery program nothing more

Comment: Maybe just scan the subkeys under `Nero\Shared\NL11` and check those beginning with `Serial11_` which's likely just one?

Comment: If there are more than one sub key it is always the first one. Not sure on the code to search for a sub key or it being the first key to search for. I did wonder about startswith but again I never used that so I'm not sure on the code.

Comment: Any examples would be a big help, thanks in advance